# Duplicate slash rewrite in Nginx server block not matching

Tags: regex, nginx

I'm attempting to write a URL rewrite to remove duplicate slashes from the URL.

After following other answers:

- [How to remove double slash in URLS served by nginx?](https://superuser.com/questions/565250/how-to-remove-double-slash-in-urls-served-by-nginx)
- [Nginx merge_slashes redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832780/nginx-merge-slashes-redirect)

I have this code

```
merge_slashes off;
rewrite (.*)//(.*) http://example.com/$1/$2 permanent;
```

However, this doesn't match any number of duplicate slashes in the URL.

Here are my test URL's

```
/page1/content.html # shouldn't match
/page1//content.html # should match and rewrite
/page1///content.html # should match and rewrite
```

I've tried these different regex strings:

```
(.*)//(.*)
(.*)/+/(.*)
(.*)//+(.*)
^(.*)//(.*)$
^(.*)/+/(.*)$
^(.*)//+(.*)$
"(.*)//(.*)"
"(.*)/+/(.*)"
"(.*)//+(.*)"
"^(.*)//(.*)$"
"^(.*)/+/(.*)$"
"^(.*)//+(.*)$"
```

None of them match.

Using a regex tester, I can see that my regex is valid and does match by itself: https://regex101.com/r/U8nghO/1/

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my full config file: https://paste.ngx.cc/286d5a2ecfc30152

Comment: Hey I am facing the same issue can you suggest me how can i prevent this

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that `merge_slashes off;` only works when in the default `server` block, or in the `http` block.

After moving the directive to my `http` block, then `(.*)//(.*)` was sufficient to catch the rewrite.

This has the side effect of turning `merge_slashes off` for all sites listening on that port.

Comment: Hey I am facing the same issue can you suggest me how can i prevent this